# Can Xcode on m1 Mac build targeting Intel

Tags: xcode

I have a 2020 m1 MacBook Pro and need to build a .dylib library targeting x86_64 architecture in order to open it in a java project that is giving me the following error:

```
mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')
```

I've checked this apple link where it says that Xcode on m1 automatically builds a universal executable https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/building-a-universal-macos-binary.

When I open my Build Settings to select the target Architecture I don't have other choices:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhn1T.png)

How can I build the way I need to?

Comment: Is it a debug build? If so underneath you have "Build for Active Architecture" setting.

Comment: Setting "Debug" to "no" did the trick, thanks

Comment: Can you please elaborate it?  Build Settings are under PROJECT and TARGET.  Which one?  And the setting name is "Build Active Architecture Only" on newer Xcode.  I set "Debug" to "No" but still same build error.  And I can't choose "Architectures" other than "$(ARCHS_STANDARD)".