# Link Intel Library to Generate Intel Binary on M1 Mac with Xcode

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, macos, apple-m1

I have 16" M1 Pro MacBook Pro.  The third party C library (.a) was built with Intel Mac and there's absolutely no way to modify the code or rebuild with M1 Mac.  The binary is x64 binary.

My project is using C++ and Objective-C++ (.mm) with Xcode.  It is targeted for Mac app and not iOS.  I want to link the C library to my project.

> The linked library 'libkfunc64.a' is missing one or more architectures
> required by this target: arm64.

I checked similar question but it didn't work:

> [Can Xcode on m1 Mac build targeting Intel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70047643/can-xcode-on-m1-mac-build-targeting-intel)

What I want to do is to generate an Intel binary.  I don't need a M1 binary or hybrid binary - I can run Intel binary on Rosetta 2 on M1 Mac.

I created a console-app with "-arch x86_64" option for LLVM C++ compiler and it worked.  But I don't know how to pass that option on Xcode.

Please tell me how to do it.  I am using Xcode 13.3.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode - Targets - Build Settings
Architectures （x86_64） or Excluded Architectures(arm64).
I've only tested the opposite.
Arm64 required, no x86_64.